# Not able to open Bootstrap modal inside partial view after form validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a Partial View that contains a modal for user login, however when there are Model State errors, the errors are shown in an entire Partial View, instead of appearing inside the Modal in the Partial View [single page appearance after validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM3ep.png)

## IdentityController.cs:

```
    public class IdentityController : MainController
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticateService _authenticationService;

        public IdentityController(IAuthenticateService authenticationService)
        {
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("authentication")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return PartialView("_UserLoginPartial");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("authentication")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("_UserLoginPartial", userLogin);

            var response = await _authenticationService.Login(userLogin);

            if (!ResponseContainsErrors(response.ResponseResult))
            {
                await ExecuteLogin(response);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            TempData["Errors"] = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v=> v.Errors.Select(e=>e.ErrorMessage)).ToList();

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Identity");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("sair")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        private async Task ExecuteLogin(UserResponseLogin response)
        {
            var token = GetFormattedToken(response.AccessToken);

            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.Add(new Claim("JWT", response.AccessToken));

            claims.AddRange(token.Claims);

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
                IsPersistent = true
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties);
        }

        private static JwtSecurityToken GetFormattedToken(string jwtToken)
        {
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(jwtToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
    }
```

## Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="userRegistrationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registrationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <partial name="_UserRegistrationPartial"></partial>
</div>
<div href="@Url.Action("Login","Identity")" class="modal fade" id="userLoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <partial name="_UserLoginPartial"></partial>

</div>
```

## _UserLoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@model WebApp.MVC.Models.UserLogin

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" text-center>
            <h5 style="text-align:center" class="modal-title heading-section" id="exampleModalLabel">Log in</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="bodyModal">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="login-wrap p-4 p-md-5">
                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <span class="fa fa-user-o"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form id="UserLoginForm" asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Identity" method="post" class="login-form">

                <vc:summary></vc:summary>


                <div class="form-group d-flex">
                    <input type="email" asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control rounded-left" id="emailLogin">
                    <small><span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span></small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group d-flex">
                    <input type="password" asp-for="Password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control rounded-left" id="passwordLogin">
                    <small><span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span></small>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="submitLoginForm" name="submitLoginForm" class="btn btn-primary rounded submit p-3 px-5">Login</button>
                    <button href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary rounded submit p-3 px-5" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeLoginModal">Close</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="text-align:center">Don't have an account? <a href="@Url.Action("Register","Identity")" id="linkRegistration" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userRegistrationModal" onclick="$('#userLoginModal').modal('hide');"><b>Sign Up</b></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using WebApp.MVC.Extensions
@inject IUser AppUser

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (AppUser.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" title="Manage">Hello @AppUser.GetUserEmail()!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Identity" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 30px;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userRegistrationModal" id="signUpLink">Sign Up</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userLoginModal" id="loginLink">Log In</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

## _Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>

    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/css/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="brand-wrap" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="section-footer border-top">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="footer-top padding-y">
            </section>

            <section class="footer-copyright border-top">
                
            </section>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The error messages are properly shown after ModelState validation but in a single page, **not inside** the modal. I've been desperately trying to solve it in the past weeks. I looked in the web and tried different approaches, but I was not able to solve it.

Any idea/suggestion that could help me solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165148/unable-to-open-bootstrap-modal-popup-from-a-partial-view

Comment: Hi, @jspcal! Thank you for your suggestion. I'm not able to use Fancybox, but I've tried the iframe template suggestion for Bootstrap, but unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the issue is that when you submit the login form, if there are errors, the page is replaced with only the HTML of the modal. If this is correct, then the core issue here is that you need to submit an AJAX request, not a normal POST request. See this line here:

```
<form id="UserLoginForm" asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Identity" method="post" class="login-form">
```

The form is set up so that when you click submit, it will do a full page refresh no matter what is returned from the controller method.

The full page refresh blows away the rest of the page and as a result you only see the modal HTML on the page.

You need to make this an AJAX form in order to do what you want here. There are various ways to handle this, but that is the core issue here. What you basically need to do is 1) Set up the form so that is submits an AJAX request, 2) When you get the response back, you'll need to add JavaScript code that replaces the login modal with the partial view HTML that is returned in the response. I would get familiar with what AJAX forms are and then research solutions for AJAX forms with .NET Core.

[EDIT] Another option, which may or may not be easier, is to keep the form the way it is, but you'll need to update this code to return the HTML for ALL of the page including the modal:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("_UserLoginPartial", userLogin);
```

This possible solution is inefficient because you are reloading the entire page instead of just the modal inside the page. Also, for this solution, you would need to add code to automatically open the login modal again since you reloaded the whole page.

Personally, I would go for the AJAX method. It will be a better user experience anyway.